# Requesting advice on a (maybe) soon to be released project = spam?

Tags: discussion, spam, site-recommendation

I have a couple of projects that I may want to release soon - code-generating programmers tools.

If I were to ask advice on Programmers (syntax tweaks, generated code style tweaks, maybe extra features), would that be appropriate? Or would it be seen as spam? Or maybe not spam, but not "good subjective" either?

I haven't decided exactly how (or when) to release the projects, but "not necessarily free or open" may be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if that's considered on-topic there, but there's another site in beta dedicated to those exact questions, **[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)**:

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for **sharing code from projects you are working on** for peer review. If you are looking for specific feedback about…
>
> - Code correctness
> - Best practices and design pattern usage in your code
> - Application UI
> - Security issues in a code snippet, etc.

Comment: +1 - I don't know how much difference it makes, but the code I would like reviewed isn't the source code for the projects themselves - only the inputs (domain specific language syntax) and outputs (code generated by the tools). OTOH, there's certainly cases that break that rule (library that the generated code requires).